# values are not being stored correctly in the array $items

Tags: laravel

I want to get the quantity of each registration type with the code below:

```
$registrationTypeDetails = Registration::with('participants:id,registration_type_id,registration_id')->find($regID);

$type_counts = [];
foreach ($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $p) {
    $name = $p->registration_type->name;
    if (!isset($type_counts[$name])) {
        $type_counts[$name] = 0;
    }
    $type_counts[$name]++;
}
```

The dd($type_counts), if the conference has 2 registration types available (general and plus) and the user is doing a registration with 2 participants  in the registration type "general" and 0 participants in the registration type "plus" shows:

```
 array:2 [▼
      "general" => 2
    ]
```

Then I need to make a post request to an API where is necessary to send in the request body the quantity of each registration type, in this case there is only 1 registration type "general" and the value for quantity should be "2".

So I have this code below the above code to create the array:

```
foreach ($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $registrationType) {
  $items['invoice']['items'][] = [
      'name' => $registrationType->registration_type->name,
      'unit_price' => $registrationType->registration_type->price,
      'quantity' => $type_counts[$registrationType->registration_type->name],
  ];
}
$create = $client->request('POST', 'https://...', [
    'query' => ['api_key' => '...'], 'json' => $items,
]);
```

But then the output array is:

```
array:1 [▼
  "invoice" => array:4 [▼
    "client" => array:7 [▶]
    "items" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:5 [▼
        "name" => "general"
        "unit_price" => 10
        "quantity" => 2
      ]
      1 => array:5 [▼
        "name" => "general"
        "unit_price" => 10
        "quantity" => 2
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Instead of only 1 item:

```
array:1 [▼
  "invoice" => array:4 [▼
    "client" => array:7 [▶]
    "items" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:5 [▼
        "name" => "general"
        "unit_price" => 10
        "quantity" => 2
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

$items shows:

```
array:1 [▼
  "invoice" => array:4 [▼

    "items" => array:2 [▼
      1 => array:5 [▼
        "name" => "general"
        "unit_price" => 10
        "quantity" => 2
      ]
      2 => array:5 [▼
        "name" => "plus"
        "unit_price" => 0
        "quantity" => 2
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to key the results of the items according to the registration type name:

```
foreach ($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $registrationType) {
  $items['invoice']['items'][$registrationType->registration_type->name] = [
      'name' => $registrationType->registration_type->name,
      'unit_price' => $registrationType->registration_type->price,
      'quantity' => $type_counts[$registrationType->registration_type->name],
  ];
}
```

Better is to use the id of the registration_type if there is one:

```
foreach ($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $registrationType) {
  $items['invoice']['items'][$registrationType->registration_type->id] = [
      'name' => $registrationType->registration_type->name,
      'unit_price' => $registrationType->registration_type->price,
      'quantity' => $type_counts[$registrationType->registration_type->name],
  ];
}
```

**Explanation**

As you loop over the participants linked to a registration type multiple participants could have the same registration type. So in your case you need to group the results according to registration type. Just adding to `items[]` appends to the items array. You want to group the results by registration type.

**Fixing the 422 validation error**

Your items is a valid array, but because it is translated to json the `1` and `1` would be keyed as an object. To force the key adjustment you can do the following:

```
// It is hacky but it re-keys the items array numerically.
$items['invoice']['items'] = array_values($list['invoice']['items']);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but can you explain why is necessary that?

Comment: It appears an error in the api post request "422 Unprocessable Entity` response: {"errors":[{"error":"Items element should be of type array"}]}".

Comment: But wth "array:1 [▼
  "invoice" => array:4 [▼
    "items" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "name" => "general"
        "unit_price" => 10
        "quantity" => 2
      ]
      1 => array:3 [▼
        "name" => "plus"
        "unit_price" => 0
        "quantity" => 2
      ]
    ]
  ]
" the error dont appears, maybe the issue is the array dont start with index 0?

Comment: Edit and update your question with the new ```items``` output and then the validation you are using for the post request.

Comment: Thanks, I update the question. It seems that is because it starts with "1" and not "0". For example with this code the error dont appears " $i=0;
        foreach ($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $registrationType) {
            $items['invoice']['items'][$i] = [
                'name' => $registrationType->registration_type->name,
                'unit_price' => $registrationType->registration_type->price,
                'quantity' => $type_counts[$registrationType->registration_type->name],
            ];
            $i++;